# Pivot table of strings excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm more versed in python/R than excel but this requires an excel specific solution, would love the guidance here!

I have a excel in the following form

```
worker id   person  question body   question answer
1   T   Q1  A1
1   T   Q2  A2
1   T   Q3  A3
1   T   Q4  A4
1   T   Q5  A5
2   A   Q1  A6
2   A   Q2  A7
2   A   Q3  A8
2   A   Q4  A9
2   A   Q5  A10
3   B   Q1  A11
3   B   Q2  A12
3   B   Q3  A13
3   B   Q4  A14
3   B   Q5  A15
```

I want the following result

```
worker id   person  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5
1   T   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
2   A   A6  A7  A8  A9  A10
3   B   A11 A12 A13 A14 A15
```

I tried using a normal pivot table with `worker id` as row, `question body` as columns, and `question answer` as data but it doesn't work as this requires a numeric answer, but the answers to the questions are strings.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Use PowerPivot with a CONCATENATEX measure, or use Power Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Query:

- Pivot on the Question column

  - No aggregation

[image]

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
            {"worker id", Int64.Type}, {"Person", type text}, {"question body", type text}, {"answer", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", 
        List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[#"question body"]), "question body", "answer")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clear guided explanation! :)